# Get curenntly loged in user Spring

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I try to get curently logged in user in spring using this code

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
```

I have a Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private PasswordEncoderConfig passwordEncoderConfig;

@Autowired
public SecurityConfig(PasswordEncoderConfig passwordEncoderConfig) {
    this.passwordEncoderConfig = passwordEncoderConfig;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    String password = passwordEncoderConfig.passwordEncoder().encode("123");
    String password2 = passwordEncoderConfig.passwordEncoder().encode("456");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("ram").password(password).roles("USER");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("ram1").password(password2).roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/drug/**").anonymous()
            .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/account/show")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll()
            .and().cors().and().csrf().disable();
}
}
```

and a Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/account")
public class AccountController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAccount(){
    final String currentUserName = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    System.out.println(currentUserName);
    return "account";
}

}
```

I want to to get username in the controller, so in that case I woud like to get *ram* printed in console. Insted it keeps returning *anonymousUser* even though I logged in as ram. What can I do to get the username?

Comment: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName(); it´s the correct way to extract the authenticated user, I use it in the same way. The only thing that occurs to me might be the in memory authentication. Maybe you could try with an in memory database or even with a real database which is easy to configure.

Answer (score 0):

antMatchers("/account/**").authenticared()

Comment: When I use it, spring doesn't redirect me to the "/account/show" page. It just keeps showing the login form over and over again

Comment: May be wrong username/pwd? No error message? Hit F12, what is the response you get after login?

Comment: the login and password are correct, there is no error message, no invalid credentials message, no any kind of message. It just keeps redirecting me to http://localhost:8080/login after using valid username and password which is pretty weird

Comment: Does it   reach controller? What is printed in console?

Comment: BTW, what is the initial URL you open?

Comment: after using .antMatchers("/account/**").authenticated() it doesn't reach the controller and doesn't print anything in the console. The initial url is /account/show

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem? I have the similar one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66467479/how-to-get-proper-user-from-securitycontextholder-authentication-within-integrat