# How to get proper user from SecurityContextHolder Authentication within integration test using rest assured?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, integration-testing, rest-assured

I cannot successfully get the right username within integration test using Rest assured. I do not understand why but Authentication from SecurityContextHolder returns "anonymousUser" instead of "myuser". What is wrong with my config?

> Response body doesn't match expectation. Expected: is "Authentication
> successful for user myuser"   Actual: Authentication successful for
> user anonymousUser

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/ping", produces = TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public class PingController {

    @GetMapping
    public @ResponseBody String ping() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return "Authentication successful for user " + authentication.getName();
    }
}
```

Security config:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/ping").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(ROLE_API)
                 
                //...another roles...

                .anyRequest().permitAll()

                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(basicRestAuthenticationEntryPoint)

                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()

                .and().cors()

                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
```

Test:

```
@Test
    void test() {
        
        given()
            .contentType(TEXT)
            .auth().basic("myuser", "password").
        when()
            .get("/api/ping").
        then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body(is("Authentication successful for user: myuser"));
    }
```